# remove HTML keywords or tags and convert to plain readable string in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Well, I have a json response with a key-value pair but in one of the key's value, I am getting this string:-

> %3chtml%3e%3cbody style%3d%27background-color%3a%27%3e%3cP style%3d%22MARGIN%3a 0in 0in 0pt%22%3e%3cSPAN style%3d%22FONT-FAMILY%3a %27Trebuchet MS%27%2c%27sans-serif%27%3b FONT-SIZE%3a 10pt%22%3eDear valued clients%2c %3c%3fxml%3anamespace prefix %3d o ns %3d %22urn%3aschemas-microsoft-com%3aoffice%3aoffice%22 %2f%3e%3co%3ap%3e%3c%2fo%3ap%3e%3c%2fSPAN%3e%3c%2fP%3e%0d%0a%3cP style%3d%22MARGIN%3a 0in 0in 0pt%22%3e%3co%3ap%3e%26nbsp%3b%3c%2fo%3ap%3e%3c%2fP%3e%0d%0a%3cP style%3d%22MARGIN%3a 0in 0in 0pt%22%3e%3cSPAN style%3d%22FONT-FAMILY%3a %27Trebuchet MS%27%2c%27sans-serif%27%3b FONT-SIZE%3a 10pt%22%3eWe are currently conducting our customer satisfaction survey 2014

I need only the string here not any tags or keywords means I need only the relevant string, like this:-

> Dear valued clients We are currently conducting our customer satisfaction survey 2014

Well I have tried using many encoding as mentioned in other answers available in stackoverflow but I failed in all. One of such is this :-

```
extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the attributed String logging to  Dear valued clients We are currently conducting our customer satisfaction survey 2014 ??

Comment: No, it is just logging the same string again.. no changes.. all the tags and keyword are intact in it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get HTML string use the below code:

```
    var htmlstring = "%3chtml%3e%3cbody style%3d%27background-color%3a%27%3e%3cP style%3d%22MARGIN%3a 0in 0in 0pt%22%3e%3cSPAN style%3d%22FONT-FAMILY%3a %27Trebuchet MS%27%2c%27sans-serif%27%3b FONT-SIZE%3a 10pt%22%3eDear valued clients%2c %3c%3fxml%3anamespace prefix %3d o ns %3d %22urn%3aschemas-microsoft-com%3aoffice%3aoffice%22 %2f%3e%3co%3ap%3e%3c%2fo%3ap%3e%3c%2fSPAN%3e%3c%2fP%3e%0d%0a%3cP style%3d%22MARGIN%3a 0in 0in 0pt%22%3e%3co%3ap%3e%26nbsp%3b%3c%2fo%3ap%3e%3c%2fP%3e%0d%0a%3cP style%3d%22MARGIN%3a 0in 0in 0pt%22%3e%3cSPAN style%3d%22FONT-FAMILY%3a %27Trebuchet MS%27%2c%27sans-serif%27%3b FONT-SIZE%3a 10pt%22%3eWe are currently conducting our customer satisfaction survey 2014"
    htmlstring = htmlstring.removingPercentEncoding!
    print("html string \(htmlstring)")
```

To get only string inside HTML use the below code

```
    let rawstr = htmlstring.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    print("rawstr \(rawstr)")
```

Comment: Excellent job !

Comment: @Vizllx. you are most welcome .  Additional info if you string has % symbol then it's percentage encoding .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out instead of using the `string` `extension`. I am currently using this code in my project.

```
do {
let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: self.alarmTitle[indexPath.row].data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
var urlString = attributedString.string
}
catch 
{
print(error)
}
```